# Do you know of a data-pump design pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented

I frequently encounter a situation where I need to write a program which reads data-objects from a file or system, does a transformation on the data, convert the data to another datamodel and then push the data in another file, or system.
Do you know of a object-model which facilitates these type of programs in such a way that it is pluggable and scalable?

Comment: It sounds like you are talking about a pipe and filter architecture?

Answer (score 1):

here's a link to an article on an alleged [Extract/Transform/Load (ETL)](http://aditiblogs.com/blog/blog/2009/03/06/etl-design-pattern-e-lt-l/) design pattern but it sounds like what you want is a framework

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I'm more looking for a GoF like design pattern, inlcuding Objects, relations etc.

Comment: @Edward: if you find one be sure to edit your question and publish it; ETL is not a GoF design pattern. There are ETL frameworks however. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

**[Read Enterprise Application Integration Patterns.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321200683)**

There is a [website related to it here](http://www.eaipatterns.com/toc.html) that contains a wealth of inter-application processing design patterns for you to browse. In particular, I'd draw your attention to these patterns:

**Messaging** 
How can I integrate multiple applications so that they work together and can exchange information?

**Message Channel**
How does one application communicate with another using messaging?

**Message Router**
How can you decouple individual processing steps so that messages can be passed to different filters depending on a set of conditions?

I've got a copy of the book myself and it's packed with detail about inter-application and inter-system design patterns.

Comment: Thanks Gary, I have the book myself :) I do appreciate this book for SOA based design, but I'm looking for a little bit more lowlevel, and need a detailed Object-design.